# Regex to accept numbers and/or number range separated by commas, but between range 1-4093

Tags: regex, string, numbers, range, vlan

I need a regex to validate  VLAN string entered by user. The string should allow numbers or ranges, separated by comma. The numbers must be between 1 and 4093.

Below samples are allowed:

```
1,
1,2,3,4
1-10, 
1-4093
4000
```

I tried below :

```
^0*([1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|[1-3][0-9]{3}|40[0-8][0-9]|409[0-3])$
```

Need to enhance for comma separated and ranges

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and what the result was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a number from 1 to 4093 one can use:

```
(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-3]))
```

That we'll call `N`. Now the repetition part:

```
^(N)(?:[,-] *(N)?)*$
```

which gives:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-3]))(?:[,-] *(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-3]\d{3}|40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-3]))?)*$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/NB5THA/1)

Comment: @Rinky please accept the answer as it helps others to identify that the problem is solved and proper credits goes to the person who answered

Answer (score 0):

regex for vlan id range 1-4093

```
(40(?:[0-8]\d|9[0-3])|[1-3]\d{2,3}|\d{2,3}|[1-9])
```